# Write swapped conditions with if-else efficiently (python)

Tags: python, if-statement

I was trying to code conditions with 2 objects, which their conditions could be swapped. Looks something like:

```
# pseudo code
if (obj_a meets condition_a and obj_b meets condition_b) or 
   (obj_a meets condition_b and obj_b meets condition_a): return True
else: return False
```

Edit: The function should return True if all conditions meets different objects in whatever order

But this seems very hard-coded, if I had more objects and more conditions, that's gonna be a bunch of identical lines with swapped conditions. How do I manage to code this efficiently? for example:

```
# objs are Capitalized, conditions have a trailing tail for easier reading. (pseudo code)
if (A.a_ and B.b_ and C.c_) or
   (A.b_ and B.c_ and C.a_) or
   (A.c_ and B.a_ and C.b_) or
   (A.b_ and B.a_ and C.c_) or
   (A.c_ and B.b_ and C.a_) or
   (A.a_ and B.c_ and C.b_): return True
else: return False
```

Comment: What about `A.b_ and B.a_ and C.c_`?

Comment: Sorry, this works too. I'll fix the code. The function should return True if all 
 conditions meets different objects in whatever order.

Comment: I don't understand why you seem to think that the order of conditions matters. Just a single `(A.a_ and B.b_ and C._)` will do.

Comment: @sorbet What if `B.a_` is `False`?

Comment: @Selcuk Oh, I see. He's using lazy evaluation. The pseudo-code hides it. edit: ok, nevermind. I misread the code (and your reply). You're right.

Comment: @selcuk Then it should return False, all conditions must meet different objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `objects` is the sequence of objects you want to apply the conditions to and `condition` is some function that checks the condition in question, then you can implement this using the builtin [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) as

```
any(condition(perm) for perm in itertools.permutations(objects))
```

Using the example from the question, we could have

```
import itertools

def condition(a, b, c) -> bool:
    return a.a_ and b.b_ and c.c_

objects = [A, B, C]

if any(condition(*perm) for perm in itertools.permutations(objects)):
   # Condition passed for some permutation.
else: 
   # Condition did not pass for any permutation.
```